# Identity Management in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have switched an MVC 5 project to MVC 6 and having some issues with the Identity Management.

As part of the sign-up process, the user selects a role which is saved in a UserRoles table using ApplicationUserManager.

In the MVC 5 version, the code in my AccoutnControler is

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

later on the in controller...

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, IsRegComplete = true};
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.Role);
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                if (model.Role == "Owner")
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Create", "Owners");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Create", "ServiceCompanies");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

As there is no IdentityConfig.cs in MVC 6 where does the ApplicationUserManager go or what replaces it to allow me to AddToRole()?

Cheers,
Kevin.

Answer (score -1):

I have not been using identity in MVC6 yet, but there are some articles in the documentation that might help you.

[Introduction to Identity](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html) and
[Migrating Authentication and Identity](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/identity.html)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer